# Conflict with ArcGIS for Desktop and Erdas Emagine on same PC?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation, erdas-imagine, arcgis-license-manager

I already installed ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

The problem is when I install th Erdas Imagine 8.6 that specify above.

So, could you help me in order to run both software products in one PC.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to specify the version of Windows that you are trying to perform these installs on, please? Then describe the steps you take to perform the installs and where what you observe departs from you would expect according to the documentation.

Comment: I think your ERDAS and ArcGIS are using same lmgrd file.Download lmtools.exe and separate them for different services..

Comment: I suspect @msi_g is correct.  If you are not comfortable with lmtools then contacting [Esri](http://support.esri.com) and/or [Hexagon Geospatial](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/support) support may be the best way forward.